# Can i change the value in a Text field on listview

Tags: java, listview, android-emulator

I have started to manage the Points and Details of a sport competition. I have displayed Competitor's ID and Name from Database. But i need to Get the Points which they got at run time Dynamically.

And the List of competitors must be changed Dynamically for verity of Games. There are Various games like Tennis, Chess, Running and so on..

Every Game that contains different Players and different no.of players. Can we Use this with `ListView`?

I need to solve this problem of Giving the points to the Competitors..

Comment: Everything you describe is possible and fairly easy in android. What exactly is it you need help on?

Comment: I have a list view with 3 columns. The first 2 columns are Id and Name. The 3rd column is EditText for entering the valated points for the Player.

Comment: Each Game will Consist of different no.of candidates in the Competition.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the listView.setAdapter(); to set the data on the listView. Also, you could add a TextView as part of the implemented getView(position, converView, view) and return it to the listView.

You could also have a tableLayout inside of the listView. You would have a seperate layout.xml file for the tableLayout. This would have 3 columns. And return this as part of the getView() method.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use the ListAdapter with TextViews and Data place holder

Comment: But Here i have not Used radio Buttons for my application